# how to restrict an animated widget's visibility to it's layout's geometry?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I have a custom widget that takes other widgets and animates them in a sliding motion. It's meant to work like the QStackedWidget, but with the requested widget dropping down from the top and "pushing" the previously visible widget out of sight.
This works more or less but I am seeing strange behaviour (such as offsets to the contained widgets and discrepancies in behaviour depending on which widgets are being added) which is causing me grieve in my main code.

After several coffees I realized that this "PageAnimator" should really be a layout manager rather than a widget, as it is only responsible for placing (and animating) other widgets.

Below is the code for my (still slightly dodgy) PageAnimator widget which I would like to turn into a proper layout manager, as that seems more logical to me.

Below the widget is the new layout manager code I managed to come up with so far. This actually seems to work ok, except for the fact that the widgets are drawn outside of the layout's geometry and I would like to make sure that they are only visible inside of it. In other words, the layout's geometry needs to become the "viewport" for the widgets.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Cheers,
frank

```py
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class PageAnimator( QWidget ):
    '''A widget that takes other widgets and animates them with a sliding motion'''
    def __init__( self, parent=None ):
        super( PageAnimator, self ).__init__( parent )
        self.pages = []
        self.visibleWidget = None
        self.end = 0

    def sizeHint( self ):
        return QSize( 400, 400 )

    def minimumSizeHint( self ):
        return QSize( 400, 400 )

    def addPage( self, widget, startPage=False ):
        '''Add this widget to the animator. If startPage is notTrue hide the widget'''
        widget.setParent( self )

        if not startPage:
            # POSITION TOOL PAGES OFF SCREEN
            widget.setGeometry(0,
                               -widget.sizeHint().height(), 
                               widget.sizeHint().width(),
                               widget.sizeHint().height())
            self.pages.append( widget )
            widget.hide()
        else:
            widget.move( (self.sizeHint().width()-widget.sizeHint().width())/2, (self.sizeHint().height()-widget.sizeHint().height())/2 )            
            self.visibleWidget = widget

    def resizeEvent( self, event ):
        '''keep visible widget centred when resizing parent'''
        widget = self.visibleWidget
        widget.move( (event.size().width()-widget.sizeHint().width())/2, (event.size().height()-widget.sizeHint().height())/5 )

    def change( self, newWidget ):
        '''Slide in the new widget and slide out the old one'''

        if newWidget == self.visibleWidget:
            return
        # Slide in
        newSize = QSize( newWidget.sizeHint().width(), self.height() )
        self.resize( newSize ) # SET VIEWPORT
        newWidget.show()

        self.animGroup = QParallelAnimationGroup()       
        slideInAnimation = self.getMoveAnimation( newWidget, -newWidget.sizeHint().height(), 0 )
        self.animGroup.addAnimation( slideInAnimation )

        # Slide out
        oldWidget = self.visibleWidget
        if oldWidget:
            #slideOutAnimation = self.getMoveAnimation( oldWidget, 0, newWidget.sizeHint().height() )
            slideOutAnimation = self.getMoveAnimation( oldWidget, oldWidget.pos().y(), newWidget.sizeHint().height() )
            self.animGroup.addAnimation( slideOutAnimation )
            slideOutAnimation.finished.connect( oldWidget.hide )

        self.animGroup.start()
        self.visibleWidget = newWidget

    def getMoveAnimation(self, widget, start, end):
        '''
        Horizontal animation, moves the widget 
        from "start" y-position to "end" y-position.
        '''
        moveAnimation = QPropertyAnimation(widget, 'pos')
        moveAnimation.setDuration( 700 )
        frameWidth = self.style().pixelMetric( QStyle.PM_DefaultFrameWidth )
        xpos = widget.pos().x()+5 # NEED TO NOT HARDCODE THE OFFSET HERE BUT CREATE IT DYNAMICALLY
        moveAnimation.setStartValue( QPoint( xpos, start ) )
        moveAnimation.setEndValue( QPoint( xpos, end ) )
        moveAnimation.setEasingCurve( QEasingCurve.OutCubic )
        return moveAnimation
```

Here is my first bit of code to mimic a QStackedLayout which I would like to turn into an animated version to replace above widget code. It has the animation bit in there but the widgets are not moving for some reason.

```
class AnimStackLayout( QLayout ):
    '''Like QStackLayout but with sliding animation'''

    def __init__( self, parent=None, duration=700 ):
        super( AnimStackLayout, self).__init__( parent )
        self.duration = duration
        self.itemList = []
        self.__currentIndex = 0

    def addItem( self, item ):
        '''add item to layout'''
        if self.count() > 0:
            item.widget().hide()
        self.itemList.append( item )

    def count( self ):
        '''return the amount of items currently held by the layout'''
        return len( self.itemList )

    def currentIndex( self ):
        '''return the current item index'''
        return self.__currentIndex

    def currentWidget( self ):
        '''return the current widget'''
        return self.itemList[ self.__currentIndex ].widget()

    def doLayout( self, rect ):
        '''do the layout work'''
        print 'doing layout work'
        x = rect.x()
        y = rect.y()
        width = rect.width()
        height = rect.height()
        for item in self.itemList:
            itemRect = QRect( x, y, width, height )
            item.setGeometry( itemRect )
            widget = item.widget()
            #widget.setVisible( widget is self.currentWidget() )


    def getMoveAnimation( self, widget, direction ):
        '''Animation, moves the widget from "start" position to "end" position.'''
        assert direction in ( 'enter', 'leave' )
        if direction == 'enter':
            start = self.geometry().y() - self.geometry().height()
            end = self.geometry().y()

        elif direction == 'leave':
            start = self.geometry().y()
            end = self.geometry().y() + self.geometry().height()

        moveAnimation = QPropertyAnimation( widget, 'pos' )
        moveAnimation.setDuration( self.duration )
        xpos = self.geometry().x()

        moveAnimation.setStartValue( QPoint( xpos, start ) )
        moveAnimation.setEndValue( QPoint( xpos, end ) )
        moveAnimation.setEasingCurve( QEasingCurve.OutCubic )
        return moveAnimation

    def itemAt( self, index ):
        '''return the item for the given index'''
        if -1 < index < self.count():
            return self.itemList[index]

    def minimumSize( self ):
        return QSize(115,18)

    def takeAt( self, index ):
        '''remove the item at the given index'''
        if -1 < index < self.count():
            return self.itemList.pop(index)
        return None

    def setCurrentIndex( self, index ):
        '''
        Set the current index to index.
        Slides the requested item's widget into view and pushes the previous one out of sight
        '''
        oldWidget = self.currentWidget()
        newWidget = self.itemList[index].widget()
        self.__currentIndex = index
        if oldWidget is newWidget:
            return

        self.animGroup = QParallelAnimationGroup()
        slideInAnimation = self.getMoveAnimation( newWidget, direction='enter'  )
        slideOutAnimation = self.getMoveAnimation( oldWidget, direction='leave' )

        slideOutAnimation.finished.connect( oldWidget.hide )
        self.animGroup.addAnimation( slideInAnimation )
        self.animGroup.addAnimation( slideOutAnimation )

        newWidget.show()
        self.animGroup.start()

    def setCurrentWidget( self, widget ):
        '''set the current widget to widget'''
        assert widget in [ item.widget() for item in self.itemList ]
        self.setCurrentIndex( self.itemList.index(widget) )

    def setGeometry( self, rect ):
        super( AnimStackLayout, self ).setGeometry( rect )
        self.doLayout( rect )

    def sizeHint( self ):
        return self.minimumSize()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    from copy import copy
    app = QApplication( sys.argv )
    # WIDGETS
    mainWidget = QWidget()
    btn1 = QPushButton( 'page A' )
    btn2 = QPushButton( 'page B' )
    frame1 = QLabel( 'A (custom layout)' )
    frame1.setFrameStyle( QFrame.Box )
    frame2 = QLabel( 'B (custom layout)' )
    frame2.setFrameStyle( QFrame.Box )
    frame3 = QLabel( 'A (default layout)' )
    frame3.setFrameStyle( QFrame.Box )
    frame4 = QLabel( 'B (default layout)' )
    frame4.setFrameStyle( QFrame.Box )

    # LAYOUTS
    mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
    stackLayout = AnimStackLayout( duration=1000 ) # MAKE THIS WORK LIKE QStackedLayout
    stackLayoutDef = QStackedLayout() # FOR COMPARISON
    mainWidget.setLayout( mainLayout )

    # PLACE WIDGETS
    stackLayout.addWidget( frame1 )
    stackLayout.addWidget( frame2 )
    stackLayoutDef.addWidget( frame3 )
    stackLayoutDef.addWidget( frame4 )

    mainLayout.addWidget( btn1 )
    mainLayout.addWidget( btn2 )
    mainLayout.addLayout( stackLayoutDef )
    mainLayout.addLayout( stackLayout )


    # CONNECT
    def changeToPage( index ):
        stackLayout.setCurrentIndex( index )
        stackLayoutDef.setCurrentIndex( index )
    btn1.clicked.connect( lambda: changeToPage(0) )
    btn2.clicked.connect( lambda: changeToPage(1) )

    # GO
    mainWidget.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Comment: The Simpsons already did it :)
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Extending_QStackedWidget_for_sliding_page_animations_in_Qt

Comment: thanks, but this is based on a QWidget again and I was wondering how to create a layout instead. However, it seems like I need to either go with a similar approach like outlined in your link or use a dummy widget to hold my layout in order to make sure child widgets are not visible outside the layout.

Comment: will mark this as solved anyway as it most certainly is a solution to my problem ;)